# loggable events in azure apim using eventhub/logger?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I've set up an EventHub and Logger in Azure.  I configured the EventHub with the default "Log to EventHub" policy:

```
    <log-to-eventhub logger-id="adc-test-logger2">
                    @( string.Join(",", DateTime.UtcNow, context.Deployment.ServiceName, context.RequestId, context.Request.IpAddress, context.Operation.Name) ) 
                </log-to-eventhub>
```

The business is interested in logging the following events:

- invalid subscription key
- invalid endpoint

I hooked into IEventProcessor to capture the info captured by the event hub logger above.  However, the info captured with this approach in its default implementation seems fairly rudimentary:

Message received.  Partition: '1', Data: '2/1/2016 7:22:17 PM,myapimaangement
.azure-api.net,caf54d02-6890-4e26-b364-b38208d1b565,40.78.99.216,Retrieve resour
ce'

How can I configure EventHub logging or the downstream listener to capture and store information which is more descriptive/useful? What is the set of useful events you have captured using this approach?

Comment: In my example I capture all of the request/response headers and a chunk of the body https://github.com/darrelmiller/ApimEventProcessor/blob/master/src/ApimEventProcessor/ApimEventProcessor.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure conditions you are looking for can be trapped by the on-error policy and are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/azure/mt629506.aspx)